# export unreal engine models with textures and materials

Tags: model, export, unreal-engine4

Can I export a complet model (with materials and textures) from unreal engine?

I tried export but i can not export the materials with them.

I need to (export them with their materials and textures)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible to export a model with the textures but you can export the materials and the textures separately.